# aligning multiple tables and their cells so their size and location are fixed in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a Nonogram game in MEAN stack. it's my first MEAN stack project and the first time I worked with these technologies though I have some experience with web development.
Essentially the game looks like several tables combined, with numbers populating 2 out of 3 tables and the third is the actual game.
[A picture I found online for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48qeE.png)
I'm using bootstrap for UI since I'm relatively familiar with it, with the help of CSS.
It's very important that the tables containing the numbers and the game board will be aligned and I can't seem to make it work, there is always a gap or the cell size is not the same.

What I tried to do is to put each table in its own td in a larger table that will contain them and control the cell size of the inner tables but it doesn't work as planned.

in game.component.html:

```
 <div id="game" class="container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <table id="columnGroup" class="table table-bordered border border-dark">
              <tr *ngFor="let line of createRange(calculateMaxArray(columnGroups)); index as i" class="border border-dark">
                <td id="cell" *ngFor="let row of createRange(width); index as j"
                class="border border-dark">
                  {{columnGroups[j][i]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table id="rowGroup" class="table table-bordered border border-dark">
              <tr *ngFor="let line of createRange(height); index as i" class="border border-dark">
                <td id="cell" *ngFor="let row of createRange(calculateMaxArray(rowGroups)); index as j"
                class="border border-dark">
                  {{rowGroups[i][j]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <app-board [width]="width" [height]="height"></app-board>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

in game.component.css:

```
#columnGroup {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0px;
}

#rowGroup {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

app-board {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  table-layout:fixed
}

#cell {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

in the board component the CSS actually worked, but I couldn't seem to replicate it to the game component.

board.component.css:

```
.empty {
  background-color: white;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../../../assets/x.svg);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

table {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5BUS.png)

Comment: Hi מיכל זוניס, welcome to SO! `Table` is not the way to go with this. Regardless of any gaming requirements, *CSS grid* or even *Flexbox Layout* would be the best choice to create a board game layout with CSS, esp. when you want to nest boards. They are also much better equipped for responsive scaling and sizing.

Comment: I just now realized you were flexbox already, but on `table` elements. That's not a good idea as both the html table and flexbox mechanisms will work against eachother. Use either or, not both. Last year I posted a demo on codepen showing how to create a Sudoku like board. I just now recreated it with only the parts relevant for you [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/wvmBedM). Let me know if this works for you...